# How do I make css3 drop shadow 'gradient'?

Tags: css

I want to create a gradient effect on a square div element using css3 drop shadow with only the left and right sides having the shadow. In other words, I am wanting to have the drop shadow start from the top dark and gradually fade lighter towards the bottom, but with roughly the quarter bottom having NO shadow at all to create a 3d, skewed square feel.

This is what I'm working from:

```
.sub_header {
 width:960px;
 height:300px;
 background:#fff;
 position:absolute; top:150px; left:50%; 
 margin-left:-480px;
 -moz-box-shadow:6px 0px 5px -5px #666, -6px 0px 5px -5px #666;
 -webkit-box-shadow:6px 0px 5px -5px #666, -6px 0px 5px -5px #666;
 box-shadow:6px 0px 5px -5px #666, -6px 0px 5px -5px #666;
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that as CSS3's box-shadow only accept colors. Instead you can emulate that gradient effect by placing an absolute div behind it.have a look at this.

```
.sub_header:before
{
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 10%; left: 10%; /*use it as you wish */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(transparent, #666); 
content: '';
}
```

This should do it.